# Why does my generic Promise retry function not behave like my specific one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a non-generic way of retrying a call out to the internet with exponential back off.  I am trying to implement it in a generic way and the way I have so far is only half working.

***The gist of it all***

The two ways of implementing this as shown below seem almost identical to me, and even work when  *request.get* is successful each and every time.

However when *request.get* throws an error randomly the retry logic works differently.  With the first non-generic method everything works as expected, calls are retried until success or *retries* == 0. With the second more generic method the retry logic fires off over and over until *retries* == 0.  It does not make the call out to the internet the second, third, fourth, ...etc., times.  What gives?

I know all of this because I have tests, under my control, that mock the *request.get()* method and either return with the proper response or with an error.

***WORKING METHOD***

OK, so I have this **working** recursive retry logic that looks like this:

```
function getPageOfThreadsWithRetry(access_token, nextPageToken, retries, delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getPageOfThreads(access_token, nextPageToken).then((results) => {
        resolve(results);
    }).catch((err) => {
      if (retries == 0) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        let retry = function() {
          retries--;
          delay = delay * DELAY_MULTIPLIER;
          resolve(getPageOfThreadsWithRetry(access_token, nextPageToken, retries, delay));
      }
      setTimeout(retry, delay);
    }
  });
});
```

*getPageOfThreads(access_token, nextPageToken)* is a simple function that returns a promise that wraps a *request.get()* call and resolves in the case of success and rejects in the case of error.

```
function getPageOfThreads(access_token, pageToken) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let options = createOptions(access_token, pageToken);
    request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        resolve(body)
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

*getPageOfThreadsWithRetry(...)* is called from inside of a **working** recursive async function that calls until there is no *nextPageToken*. The call looks like:

```
let delay = INIT_RETRY_DELAY;
let retries = MAX_RETRIES;
let response = await getPageOfThreadsWithRetry(access_token, nextPageToken, retries, delay).catch((error) => {

});
```

This works as expected, *getPageOfThreads()* is called and returns the *response* object just fine over and over until there is no nextPageToken. 
 If an error is randomly thrown somewhere in there it just retries the call with exponential back off until either it succeeds or it has tried more then *retries* times.

***HALF WORKING METHOD***

I would like to implement this kind of thing in many places throughout my app.  Thus I am trying to come up with a generic utility function that will do this.  So far I have come up with this (prms == promise in this case):

```
function retryPromise(prms, retries, delay, delayMultiplier) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    prms.then((results) => {
      resolve(results);
    }).catch((err) => {
      if (retries == 0) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        let retryFunc = function() {
          retries--;
          delay = delay * delayMultiplier;
          resolve(retryPromise(prms, retries, delay, delayMultiplier));
        }
        setTimeout(retryFunc, delay);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Trying to call it like so:

```
function getPageOfThreadsWithRetry(access_token, nextPageToken) {
  let delay = INIT_RETRY_DELAY;
  let retries = MAX_RETRIES;
  let delayMultiplier = DELAY_MULTIPLIER;
  let prms = getPageOfThreads(access_token, nextPageToken);
  return retryPromise(prms, retries, delay, delayMultiplier);
}
```

and calling *getPageOfThreadsWithRetry()* from up top in a similar way as before

```
let response = await getPageOfThreadsWithRetry(access_token, nextPageToken).catch((err) => {
});
```

This second way is preferable to me as it can be implemented anywhere I have a call out to the internet and abstracts away details for all of the code that depends on the response from the internet.

I know this is a rather complex question, so I really really appreciate anyone who is willing to give it some thought and time, and especially anyone who may have the answer?

Even if your answer involves a completely different way to do this I would love to learn what you may know.

-Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first method, `request.get` is called inside the recursive function `getPageOfThreadsWithRetry`. But in your second method, `request.get` is called outside the recursive function `retryPromise`.

I would recommend you change the `retryPromise` signature to something like

```js
function retryPromise(promiseCreator, retries, delay, delayMultiplier) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promiseCreator()
      .then(resolve)
      .catch((err) => {
        if (retries == 0) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          let retryFunc = function() {
            retries--;
            delay = delay * delayMultiplier;
            resolve(retryPromise(promiseCreator, retries, delay, delayMultiplier));
          }
          setTimeout(retryFunc, delay);
        }
      });
  });
}
```

and use it like

```js
function getPageOfThreadsWithRetry(access_token, nextPageToken) {
  let promiseCreator = () => getPageOfThreads(access_token, nextPageToken);
  return retryPromise(promiseCreator, retries, delay, delayMultiplier);
}
```

Comment: OH wow, that's actually working...and I learned something deeper about javascript today! Super SUPER appreciate the help. Just going to make a couple quick edits to the miss-spelling that I had when I first posted that seem to have carried over to your (fast and very correct) answer.